# Value matrix with weight matrix

Tags: matrix, optimization, resources

I have two non square matrix say V and W of same size. First matrix (V) is the value matrix which tell the resource value of i<sup>th</sup> row for j<sup>th</sup> col in cell (ij) of matrix V. The ij<sup>th</sup> value of other matrix (W) tell the weight. The objective is to maximize the profit which is the sum of product of value and weight i.e. sum(V<sup>ij</sup>W<sup>ij</sup>) with some additional constraint. The variable is weight matrix i.e. its value can be change. The other constraint are resultant weight should be binary and in any row of W, and the row sum cant be more than 2 i.e.
[image] and if Wij > 0, then kij = 1 else kij = 0

What is the best way to solve the problem in Python?

I tried to solve it by using assignment problem but I am not able to use weight matrix.